# Single Sign On SAML service failing to decrypt

Tags: php, saml, onelogin

I'm implementing the service provider side of a Single Sign On solution. We are using PHP and the samlphp library provided by Onelogin. Everything is going pretty well. The user can attempt to access our service and is redirected to the IDP login. Once they login there they are redirected back to our site.

This is where the problem occurs. Once back at our site we get an error...

```
<Entry reference="REF_56dea40aa6419" TimeStamp="2016/03/08 12:06:02" Category="Exception" Type="Error"><![CDATA[

Description         Failure decrypting Data
File  Library/SSO/OneLogin/extlib/xmlseclibs/xmlseclibs.php
Line                357
Class               Exception
Stack               

UI                  Business console
User                -
Code                0
When                2016/03/08 12:06:02
URL called          https://stage.icky-yuk.co.za/?acs
Referred by         https://signon.blarg.co.za/adfs/ls/?SAMLRequest=hVNdrxIxEH038T%2BQfWc%2FgYsNYBD8IEEggD74YsZ2gCbddu10vVx%2Fvd2l5KJR7MsmM3NOzzmdHRGUqmLT2p30Fr%2FXSO7li44%2F51JpYm13HNVWMwMkiWkokZjjbDf9uGR5nLLKGme4UdGfuPswIELrpNEBt5iPo%2FXq7XL9frH6iv2ByDjvwzDvYZr3Hl7lw%2F6gKHp9gCLvpUWRP4iC5wH7GS15pnHkiX0pEBLVuNDkQDvfSbNBNy266XCfpSwdsDT7EtBz71lqcC3DybmKWJKQPGqjY6NEWbsaVMxN%2FBMSEAdKFCUBugne30gtpD7ed%2FztMkTsw36%2F6W7Wu31gmV6jmBlNdYl2h%2FaH5Phpu7wR5OCIsbHyKDU9kcOSgqbXwCmaXKhGTfCstW4n%2F4eW6ECAg7g6VaPkFntDV7GV97KYb4yS%2FOnSaM47Y0tw%2F%2FacxVlbkaJ7aEcZliDVVAiLRNEz0VQp8zizCA7HkbM1Rp3kdwFhM1G0e%2Bpjcnh2nZkpK7CSmnfDM3B3TeE5idv5mfI7t8XD5O5acsabOV%2Fe%2BM%2BjsaJ5ZOT%2B8r0FTZWxLkT1V%2FKgO7kj3M9c%2B7f%2F3eQX&RelayState=https%3A%2F%2Fstage.icky-yuk.co.za%2F
]]></Entry>
```

The metadata we are using with the SAML toolkit follows. It is in array form but I've spit it out json encoded so it is easier to read.

```
{
    "sp": {
        "entityId": "https:\/\/stage.icky-yuk.co.za\/metadata.php",
        "assertionConsumerService": {
            "url": "https:\/\/stage.icky-yuk.co.za\/?acs"
        },
        "singleLogoutService": {
            "url": "https:\/\/stage.icky-yuk.co.za\/?slo"
        },
        "NameIDFormat": "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress"
    },
    "idp": {
        "entityId": "http:\/\/signon.blarg.co.za\/adfs\/services\/trust",
        "singleSignOnService": {
            "url": "https:\/\/signon.blarg.co.za\/adfs\/ls\/",
            "binding": "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"
        },
        "singleLogoutService": {
            "url": "https:\/\/signon.blarg.co.za\/adfs\/ls\/",
            "binding": "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"
        },
        "x509cert": "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"
    }
}
```

I've double-checked the x509 certification and it is good. I admit I'm not a SAML or Single Sign On expert by any stretch of the imagination. I'm obviously overlooking something here. Is there some other component to the encryption beyond the cert? I'm not sure where to look anymore.

Comment: Tried to base64 decode the SAMLResponse, but failed. There might be an encryption scheme on token level that I'm not familiar with. But anyway, SAML encryption/decryption is usually done via another certificate-private key; not the certificate provided in the metadata. That's only used for signature verification. According to my limited experience, typically you upload a certificate to IdP and configure your service provider with the matching private key.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. It ended up being that the key file wrong. Not sure how that happened but given how we were changing things in and out to test stuff, I'm not terribly surprised that the wrong key file got matched with the certification.

Answer (score 1):

If the IdP is sending an encrypted SAML Response, why there is no public cert private key on the 'sp' section of the provided settings?: 
'x509cert' and  'privateKey'

Or you have them defined as files on the cert folder?

The SP x509cert must be shared with the IdP for encrypt the Assertion (SP will decrypt with SP private key).

P.S I wasn't able to decode the SAMLRequest but it seems a LogoutRequest..not related with the supposed SAMLResponse recieved.